# Connecting python program to mysql safely

Tags: python, mysql

I want to connect to MySQL from my python program using MySQLdb.

I am worried because I need to put username and password in the `.py` in order to connect to MySQL database, as well into inno setup.

Couldn't anybody find the user name and password and get access to my database? How do I solve this problem? Do I make a sql user with limited access somehow? (I am new to html/css/MySQL).

Comment: ask for the user to input the user and pass instead of hard coding it.

Comment: Make the file readable only by a certain user. If someone has root access to your computer, they're going to get your passwords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure your MySQL user/password is different than your  username and password.

Next, make a file called, say, `config.py` and place it in a directory in your PYTHONPATH:

```
USER='zzzzzzzz'
PASS='xxxxxxxx'
HOST='yyyyyyyy'
MYDB='wwwwwwww'
```

Change the permissions on the file so only you (and root) can read it. For example, on Unix:

```
chmod 0600 /path/to/config.py
```

Now, when you write a script using `MySQLdb` you'd write

```
import config
connection = MySQLdb.connect(
    host = config.HOST, user = config.USER,
    passwd = config.PASS, db = config.MYDB)
```

So your username and password will not appear in any of your scripts.

---

You could also put `config.py` in an encrypted directory, and/or on a USB thumb drive, so the file is only accessible when the drive is mounted.