# Connect to MySQL in Python: the safe way?

Tags: python, mysql

Normally, if I connect to MySQL using some API (say, in Python on Linux), I have to supply the password as an argument of the `connect()` function. However, I don't want to store the password in the code, or even anywhere in the project repository, because I'm going to share it. I also don't want to pass it as a command-line argument, because firstly, it's going to be visible in the process manager, secondly, I don't want to type it every time I start the script. I also don't want a program-specific config file for every small script.

I came up with the following solution: parse the local `~/my.cnf` file (in Python e.g. using `configparser`) and get the default settings from there. However, I have to do the parsing myself and use the inconvenient "group suffixes" if I want to work with multiple hosts.

So my question is: is there a standard way to safely store a default password for a pair (host, user), which various scripts/programs could use?

EDIT: I've found a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375412/connecting-python-program-to-mysql-safely?rq=1), but I'm not satisfied with the answer there, because it's still storing password in the code.

Comment: Always use environment variables for things like this. See [12 Factor apps](https://12factor.net/config).

Comment: You could also set up another account that you don't care about sharing with everyone

Comment: Why not just make a config file that is re-used among all your "small" scripts? Parsing the local my.cnf file sounds insecure, as you would have to provide the application with access to that file.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks for the suggestion. However, the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-security-user.html) calls using environment variables "extremely insecure".

Comment: Using `~/.my.cnf` with a [defaults group suffix](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-file-options.html#option_general_defaults-group-suffix) seems like a fine solution, especially if you're already using that file to store credentials for the MySQL CLI utilities. More recent versions try to do some [obfuscation of the passwords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-config-editor.html), but I don't how how rigorous / advisable that is. I'm definitely going to look into this. In a Unix environment, you could create a `.my.cnf` solely for the user running the web application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can connect to database without the password unless you create an user without a password. There is very common and safe for the projects that are on github or any other repository system to have a dist file that is included the in the repository and the real config file to be ignored. Something like this:

```
config/
  - settings.dist.py
  - settings.py
```

and your system will load `settings.py` where you'll have your database credentials or the application specific settings. This file will not be on the repository because it will be ignored.
On the repository you'll have only `settings.dist.py` with default credentials for local dev environment, so anyone who will join the project will use their own credentials. On live should not be access to everyone.

```
git add settings.dist.py
echo "settings.py" >> .gitignore
git commit -m 'yout message'
git push origin branch_name
```